# Update multiple row Trigger + Json Parsing (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

First of all I want to say that this is my first post here so excuse me in advance if I don't present it correctly

I'm new to SQL and I'm currently trying to create a Trigger that allows me to split into several columns what I receive in Json.

After a lot of research I managed to make a script to do this:

```sql
SELECT
datajson2,
 JSON_VALUE([datajson2],'$.IdDevice') AS IdDevice,
 JSON_VALUE([datajson2],'$.code') AS CodeDevice,
 MaterialId_CapacityParsing.MaterialId,
  MaterialId_CapacityParsing.MaterialCapacity
FROM
 [dbo].[JsonTest]
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([datajson2])
 WITH(
   MaterialId_Capacity NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.material' AS JSON
  ) AS MaterialMessage 
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([MaterialId_Capacity])
 WITH(
   MaterialId NVARCHAR(100) '$.id',
   MaterialCapacity NVARCHAR(100) '$.capacity'
  ) AS MaterialId_CapacityParsing
WHERE 
 ISJSON([datajson2]) > 0
```

Input :

```
[
{
 
  "code": "device_spec",
    "IdDevice" : "1",
    "material": [
    {"id": "1", "capacity": 10000},
    
    {"id": "2", "capacity": 10000}, 
    
    {"id": "3", "capacity": 100},
   
    {"id": "4", "capacity": 1000}, 
    
    {"id": "5", "capacity": 1000}
    ]
},
{
  "code": "device_spec",
    "IdDevice" : "2",
    "material": [
    {"id": "1", "capacity": 0},
    
    {"id": "2", "capacity": 10000}, 
    
    {"id": "3", "capacity": 50000},
   
    {"id": "4", "capacity": 1000}, 
    
    {"id": "5", "capacity": 1000}
    ] 
}

]
```

Output :  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOuOF.png

This is exactly what I want, but the next step would be to have a Trigger do this automatically on each insertion. So I tried something like this:

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[testJsonParse]
ON [dbo].[JsonTest]
AFTER INSERT 
AS BEGIN 

UPDATE [dbo].[JsonTest]
SET
IdDevice = JSON_VALUE([datajson2],'$.IdDevice') ,
CodeDevice = JSON_VALUE([datajson2],'$.code'),
MaterialId =
( SELECT 
 MaterialId_CapacityParsing.MaterialId 
FROM
[dbo].[JsonTest] 
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([datajson2])
 WITH(
   MaterialId_Capacity NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.material' AS JSON
  ) AS MaterialMessage 
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([MaterialId_Capacity])
 WITH(
   MaterialId NVARCHAR(100) '$.id'
  ) AS MaterialId_CapacityParsing
  WHERE MaterialId_CapacityParsing.MaterialId  IN ('1','2','3','4','5'))
END
```

The first two(IdDevice and CodeDevice) work but as soon as I try to assign my MaterialId column it doesn't work anymore

And even after several hours of changing the code I still get the same error when I try to insert data with this query:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I am missing something, if someone could tell me what it is, it would be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: Your trigger doesn't ever reference the `inserted` pseudo table; that doesn't seem right. Do you *really* want to `UPDATE` **every** row in the table `JsonTest` when 0 or more rows are `INSERT`ed into the table?

Comment: The error, however, is also telling you the problem. You can see in the image you uploaded that your subquery clearly returns more than 1 values; there are *many* rows in that image. Your subquery **cannot** return more than 1 column or row in the context it is used in.

Comment: The idea was that I receive the json in a column that creates a row, I then update only this row by assigning to the column what is contained in the json.
My logic is not the right one for this problem ?
Yes the problem seems logical to me... but I don't see how to solve it.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] containing your sample JSON, as well as your table schema. Why don't you just use computed columns? Something like `ALTER TABLE JsonTest ADD IdDevice AS JSON_VALUE([datajson2],'$.IdDevice') ADD CodeDevice = JSON_VALUE([datajson2],'$.code')`

Comment: _The idea was that I receive the json in a column that creates a row_ This idea comes from whom? Why bother with this in the backend when the process that inserts the data likely has equivalent (or better) functionality to do this (perhaps matched by the skill level of the developers)?